# How to delete yarn logs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm pretty new to YARN. I ran my oozie jobs which creates logs.

I can see yarn logs with

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_123456789_12345678
```

I want to know how I can delete those logs? Can I just delete the file to remove the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no yarn commands to delete yarn logs from CLI.

You can delete by using Linux `rm` by going to the yarn log directory `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` `/application_${appid}`. Individual containers log directories will be below this, in directories named `container_{$contid}`. Each container directory will contain the files `stderr`, `stdin`, and `syslog` generated by that container.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this. I didn't find any command to delete that. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 13):

Once the job has completed the NodeManager will keep the log for each container for `${yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds}` which is 10800 seconds by default ( 3 hours ) and delete them once they have expired.  But if `${yarn.log-aggregation-enable}` is enabled then the NodeManager will immediately concatenate all of the containers logs into one file and upload them into HDFS in `${yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir}/${user.name}/logs/<application ID>` and delete them from the local userlogs directory

[Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) indicates `yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec`:

Number of seconds after an application finishes before the nodemanager's DeletionService will delete the application's localized file directory and log directory. To diagnose Yarn application problems, set this property's value large enough (for example, to 600 = 10 minutes) to permit examination of these directories. After changing the property's value, you must restart the nodemanager in order for it to have an effect. The roots of Yarn applications' work directories is configurable with the yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property (see below), and the roots of the Yarn applications' log directories is configurable with the `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` property (see also below).

You must configure `yarn-default.xml`:

```
  <property>
    <description>
      Number of seconds after an application finishes before the nodemanager's DeletionService will delete the application's localized file directory and log directory.
    </description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
```

Maybe retain seconds can be useful:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds</name>
<value>3600</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to delete these logs manually. How do I delete them explicitly?

Comment: Just adding that it is JobHistory server that handles the periodic deletion of the app-logs in ${yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir}. Thought it was worth mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete ${yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir}/${user}/${application_id}/...
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/running-on-yarn.html#debugging-your-application  look this

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to explain what it does and how it improves on the 2 year old accepted answer.