# Cleanup yarn container logs for Spark streaming app

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have a long running Spark streaming job, running in yarn mode with log aggregation enabled.
Every few weeks, the streaming job gets killed with "RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM".

Looking closer, I see below alert getting fired due to local disk space reaching 90% filled threshold. This is likely due to the container logs from Spark streaming job.

How can I clean up these logs in a long running streaming job, without shutting down the app? Is there some setting to enable auto cleanup?

```
YARN    NODEMANAGER     NodeManager Health
        CRITICAL 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local;
 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/log
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817924/cleaning-up-spark-history-logs

Comment: Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195478/how-to-delete-yarn-logs the second read the second answer.

Comment: Thanks. Soheil, the second link referenced talks about deleting logs after app shutdown. I am looking for deleting old logs while the app is still running.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?